# What is JavaScript regex for string matches which starts with $$ and ends with $$?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want Javascript regex for all strings that start with $$ and ends with $$

example:

```
$$hello$$
$$world$$
```

Comment: you have two answers below, other is greedy and other non-greedy. Left as an exercise to work out what that means. Both are valid answers.

Comment: @eis: The greediness of the answers, though, is a distinction without a difference in this case, isn't it? What with anchors at both ends, the greediness of the bit in the middle is irrelevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but I thought it's worth a mention anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
^\${2}.*?\${2}$
```

How this works: first, you look for two dollar signs, then, it allows any input, and then it looks whether the string ends with two dollar signs.

Answer (score 3):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^\$\$.*\$\$$
```

This will match the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by `$$`, followed by zero or more of any character, followed by `$$`, and the end of the string (`$`). For example:

```
/^\$\$.*\$\$$/.test('$$hello$$') // true
```

If you're looking for a *substring* of a larger string which matches this pattern, use something like this:

```
\$\$.*?\$\$
```

This will match `$$`, followed by zero or more of any character, non-greedily, followed by `$$`. For example:

```
/\$\$.*?\$\$/.exec('print "$$hello$$"') // ['$$hello$$']
```

But for something this simple, you can just use plain old string manipulation:

```
var string = '$$hello$$';
var result = (string.substr(0, 2) == '$$') && (string.substr(-2) == '$$'); // true
```

Comment: Actually i want to match that pattern in javascript, but that doesnt seem to work. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/G7R5n/1/. I replaced the regex with the keyword but doesnt work. Please help

Comment: @Raghav See my updated answer. `\$\$.*?\$\$` should work.